# Woocommerce: get product variation title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a plugin and cannot get the correct variation title
In Woocommerce the variation i use is called "unfolded laminated". but when i try to get the title of a variation i get: "Variation #781 of Chart"

This is the code is use:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    if ($product_variation_id)
    {
        $product = new WC_Product($product_variation_id);
        $productname = get_item_variations($product_variation_id);
    }
    else
    { 
        $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
        $productname = get_the_title($item['product_id']);
    } 
}
```

How do i get the correct title?

Answer (score 3):

I was actually looking this up trying to figure it out and here's my solution because the variation title was returning a slug.

Tested on WC 2.4.13

```
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$title_slug = current($variation->get_variation_attributes());

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE slug = '{$title_slug}'", ARRAY_A);
$variation_title = $results[0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this just now looking for a 'quick' fix. Since no-one has posted an answer I thought I would.

I just used WordPress `get_post_meta` to fetch `attribute_options`. This is where all the option titles are stored (variation titles are product options).

```
$product_options = get_post_meta($item['variation_id'], 'attribute_options');
```

Will return an array

```
    [attribute_options] => Array
    (
        [0] => Some Variation Title
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for this problem which is tested with **WooCommerce 3.2.6**

```
//Loop through each item from the cart
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
  //get the current product ID
  $product_id  = $cart_item['product_id'];
  //first - check if product has variations
  if(isset($cart_item['variation']) && count($cart_item['variation']) > 0 ){
    //get the WooCommerce Product object by product ID
    $current_product = new  WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
    //get the variations of this product
    $variations = $current_product->get_available_variations();
    //Loop through each variation to get its title
    foreach($variations as $index => $data){
      get_the_title($data['variation_id']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function to return the title of the input variation, you can change the delimiter ', ' to a space or whatever is needed.

```
function get_variation_title($variation) {

    $str_name = '';

    $arr_attributes = $variation -> get_variation_attributes(FALSE);

    if (is_array($arr_attributes)) {
        foreach($arr_attributes as $attribute_slug=> $variation_slug) {
            $term = get_term_by('slug', $variation_slug, $attribute_slug);

            if (isset($term)) {
                if (strlen($str_name) > 0) $str_name.= ', ';
                $str_name.= $term -> name;
            }
        }
    }

    return $str_name;
}
```