# Woocommerce: get_formatted_name() of a variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the name of a variation in woocommerce, currently im using this:

```
$variationDetails = wc_get_product($variation_id);
$variationDetails->get_formatted_name();
```

But get_formatted_name() returns a long string with too many details, I only need the simple name of the variation. I've tried with $variationDetails->get_title() but that returns only the product title instead the variation name.

Is there a simple function to get the variation name?

Comment: This could be helpful *(may be)*: [Woocommerce: get product variation title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741270/woocommerce-get-product-variation-title)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hopefully this helps had the same problem recently this is what I wrote to get the variations title for a product

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variation_names = array();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

// Get attribute taxonomies
$taxonomies = array_keys($variation['attributes']);

// Loop through variation taxonomies to get variation name and slug
foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
    $get_term_tax = str_replace('attribute_', '', $tax);
    $meta = get_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], $tax, true );
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $meta, $get_term_tax );
    $var_name = $term->name;
    $variation_names[] = $var_name;
}
}
```